# How to get row's and cell's index of a just edited cell in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm having problem with finding row's and cell's index of a just edited cell in `DataGrid`.
I'm using `CellEditEnding` event to know when the cell has been edited.

Till now I've managed to do something like this. `Col1` contains property `DisplayIndex` and that is index of selected column but I can't find in the same way.

```
    private void DataGridData_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridColumn col1 = e.Column;
        DataGridRow row1 = e.Row;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've got it working now. This is how it looks like:

```
private void DataGridData_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridColumn col1 = e.Column;
        DataGridRow row1 = e.Row;
        int row_index = ((DataGrid)sender).ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(row1);
        int col_index = col1.DisplayIndex;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but for anyone who finds this question this code will work by adding this event to your datagrid:

```
private void dgMAQ_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.EditingElement;
            string newText = string.Empty;

        //Check if the item being edited is a textbox
        if (dep is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox txt = dep as TextBox;
            if (txt.Text != "")
            {
                newText = txt.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                newText = string.Empty;
            }
        }
        //New text is the new text that has been entered into the cell

       //Check that the value is what you want it to be
        double isDouble = 0;
        if (double.TryParse(newText, out isDouble) == true)
        {

            while ((dep != null) && !(dep is DataGridCell))
            {
                dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
            }

            if (dep == null)
                return;


            if (dep is DataGridCell)
            {
                DataGridCell cell = dep as DataGridCell;

                // navigate further up the tree
                while ((dep != null) && !(dep is DataGridRow))
                {
                    dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
                }

                if (dep == null)
                    return;

                DataGridRow row = dep as DataGridRow;
                int rowIndex = row.GetIndex();

                int columnIndex = cell.Column.DisplayIndex;

        //Check the column index. Possibly different save options for different columns
                if (columnIndex == 3)
                {

                    if (newText != string.Empty)
                    {
                        //Do what you want with newtext
                    }
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the row-index without a 'sender' argument you might try:

```
 Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Header)
```

combined with an abbreviated form of Patryk's answer this gives:

```
 private void DataGridData_CellEditEnding(DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        int col1 = e.Column.DisplayIndex;
        int row1 = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Header);
    }
```